# Javascript difference between MyClass.prototype = {} and MyClass.prototype.method

Tags: javascript, prototype

This is one thing I was wondering for a long time. But first example code for both

### Type A

```
var JavaScriptClass = function () {

};


JavaScriptClass.prototype = {
    myMethodOne: function() {

    },

    myMethodTwo: function() {

    }
};
```

### Type B

```
var JavaScriptClass = function () {

};

JavaScriptClass.prototype.myMethodOne = function(){

};

JavaScriptClass.prototype.myMethodTwo = function(){

};
```

I saw both in lots of tutorials, examples and libraries (subjective Type A in the older ones).

For me it is more comfortable to use Type A especially in large classes, because you have to write less code. But as I know the compiler of coffeescript compiles the `Class` statement to Type B.

Is there a considerable difference between Type A and B (e.g. performance, advantages with inheritance, or better IDE support) or is this only a "coding style" thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a considerable difference.

In Type A, you're **reassigning** the prototype property of the function, in Type B, you're **extending** it (by reassigning certain methods). This would not be different if nobody else touched the prototype, but actually functions come with a prototype property by default.

Try this: type into the console

```
var a=function(){console.log(123);};
```

Then access the prototype of this newly created function:

```
a.prototype;
```

In a browser environment this logs an object with a `constructor` and a `__proto__` attribute. If you do Type A, a.prototype will be your object entirely, in Type B, you're extending this object with methods `myMethodOne` and `myMethodTwo`.

As for the practical difference (which mostly plays a role when you want to use this function as a constructor function), particularly on *why* a function has a default prototype *property* at all (not to be confused with the prototype on the prototype chain of the created function), let me quote [Eloquent Javascript, chapter 6:](http://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html)

> It is important to note the distinction between the way a prototype is associated with a constructor (through its `prototype` property) and the way objects *have* a prototype (which can be retrieved with `Object.getPrototypeOf`). The actual prototype of a constructor is `Function.prototype` since constructors are functions. Its `prototype` property will be the prototype of instances created through it but is not its own prototype.